# php can't connect to the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code

```
 $db_handle = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '123456');
    if(!$db_handle)
        die(mysql_error())
```

when i was debugging the code just got a page with "This page can't be display", and the a pop up message from netbean said " Socket Exception occured", can anyone help? thanks

**edit**
new code:

```
$db_handle = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','admin','123456');
    if($db_handle)
        echo 'connected';
```

it works, but the mysqli didn't work either

Comment: You shouldn't use the `mysql_*` functionality. You should be using the `PDO` object, or the `mysqli` functions.

Comment: Also it is a VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY bad idea to connect as root.

Comment: is your mysql set up to use tcp connections? generally it's not and defaults to local unixdomain sockets only.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with your code. More likely there's something wrong with the setup of you web server. Are you able to run a php file with this code? `phpinfo();`

Comment: @Jules yes, i can run phpinfo()

Comment: try to add a `;` after `die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score 1):

Please stop using `mysql_query` for new project, use mysqli or PDO

Here a sample:

```
mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $dbpassword, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I'd -1 for saying the db name is missing. it's an **OPTIONAL** parameter. but pushing for mysqli/pdo makes up for it.

Comment: I tried your code too got the same error. Is it possible that the code is fine because the page even didn't show the connection error, maybe some configuration was wrong? I check the mysql workbench, the connection method is standard(TCP/IP)

Comment: Are you sure port is set, database is running and there is no firewall rule block connection somewhow?

Comment: @Fabio yes, I checked the mysql, and turned off the firewall, the problem is still there, getting crazy

Answer (score 0):

$db_handle = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','admin','123456');
    if($db_handle)
        echo 'connected';